# Extending or cloning File Web API object in Redux reducer to support other properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, fileapi

I'm trying to keep an array of files that a user has selected to upload. Each file is a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object. I would like to add other properties to it, like 'progress' and 'status' so that I can present this data to a user when they begin the upload process.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to 'copy' a File object using `Object.assign()` or the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` approach, I'm only ever getting back the properties that I have set myself, not the values inherent to the object.

This is an example of one of my attempts to use `Object.assign()`:

```
Object.assign({}, state, {
    files: [
        ...state.files.slice(0, payload.index),
        Object.assign({}, state.files[payload.index], {
            status: 'UPLOADING',
            progress: 0
        }),
        ...state.files.slice(payload.index + 1)
    ]
})
```

Understandably, this causes me all sorts of problems...

What is a good way of keeping track of files and being able to extend their properties in a Redux-suitable manner?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't try to store your extra properties on the `File` object.  Instead store them as siblings on a parent object:

```
// INIT case
return {
    ...state,
    files: [
        ...state.files,
        { fileObject, status: "INITIAL" }
    ]
};

// UPDATE case
return {
    ...state,
    files: [
        ...state.files.slice(0, payload.index),
        { ...state.files[payload.index], status: "UPLOADING", progress: 0 },
        ...state.files.slize(payload.index + 1)
    ]
};
```

In this scheme:

```
// fileObject is the File
const { fileObject, status, progress } = state.files[2];
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess was just having one of those days... :S